# Как разобрать XML в дерево объектов разных типов (классов)

Tags: java, xml, парсер

Добрый день.
Прошу направить на верный путь.
Есть сложный XML файл (выдает IBM HMC через Rest API).
В нем присутствует дерево разных сущностей.
К примеру:
сервер -> сетевой_адаптер -> vlan и т.п.
сервер -> Processor_pool -> Processor и т.п.
Ходить по дереву я научился. Создав классы каждой сущности (сервер, сет.адаптер и т.п.)  наполняю свойства объектов через сетеры.
Но на мой взгляд все это как-то коряво...
Во первых нет взаимосвязи/иерархии объектов
 
Во вторых это жутко сложный ручной труд
Пример XML сильно упрощенный:

```
    ..
<entry>
    <AssociatedSystemProcessorConfiguration kxe="false" kb="CUD" schemaVersion="V1_5_1">
        ...
        <ConfigurableSystemProcessorUnits kxe="false" kb="ROR">8</ConfigurableSystemProcessorUnits>
    </AssociatedSystemProcessorConfiguration>
    <AssociatedSystemIOConfiguration kxe="false" kb="CUD" schemaVersion="V1_5_1">
        ...
        <IOBus schemaVersion="V1_5_1">
            <IOSlots kxe="false" kb="ROR" schemaVersion="V1_5_1">
                <IOSlot schemaVersion="V1_5_1">
                    <Description kxe="false" kb="CUD">Dual 1 Gigabit Ethernet-TX PCI-X Adapter</Description>
                </IOSlot>
            </IOSlots>
        </IOBus>
        ...
    </AssociatedSystemIOConfiguration>
</entry>
<entry>
    <AssociatedSystemProcessorConfiguration kxe="false" kb="CUD" schemaVersion="V1_5_1">
        ...
        <ConfigurableSystemProcessorUnits kxe="false" kb="ROR">44</ConfigurableSystemProcessorUnits>
    </AssociatedSystemProcessorConfiguration>
    <AssociatedSystemIOConfiguration kxe="false" kb="CUD" schemaVersion="V1_5_1">
        ...
        <IOBus schemaVersion="V1_5_1">
            <IOSlots kxe="false" kb="ROR" schemaVersion="V1_5_1">
                <IOSlot schemaVersion="V1_5_1">
                    <Description kxe="false" kb="CUD">Dual 4 Gigabit Ethernet-TX PCI-X Adapter</Description>
                </IOSlot>
            </IOSlots>
        </IOBus>
        ...
    </AssociatedSystemIOConfiguration>
</entry>
..
```

Напрашивается использование какой-нибудь коллекции в виде дерева, в которой можно хранить ссылки на объекты разных типов. Но пока не могу подступиться.
В тоже время, наверняка есть уже готовые механизмы способные пройтись по дереву XML и составить из этого многоуровневое дерево объектов.
Прошу подсказать.

Comment: Можно пример XML?

Comment: Добавьте тег, какой язык используется (Java, C# и т. п.)

Comment: Чем вы научились ходить по дереву? А то существует не меньше десятка способов разбирать xml в java.